# Grunt coffee with node requires() support

Tags: file, include, coffeescript, gruntjs

Have seen a couple of solutions re: being able to include `.coffee` files within a coffee file directly via nodejs:

For example, given jform.coffee:

```
jForm = {
  foo: () -> console.log('blah')
}
exports.jForm = jForm
```

I would love to be able to include jform.coffee in *other coffee source files* a la:

```
jForm = requires('jform.coffee').jForm
```

but this approach does not seem to work with [Grunt's officially supported coffee contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee)...or maybe I'm just missing something?

LESS is awesome with the `@import` option, makes it easy to modularize things without a cluster f*ck of `Gruntfile.js` text to slog through ;-)

Did run across [this plugin](https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat) with coffee requires support, but would prefer, if possible, going with Grunt contrib coffee.

Comment: Why would you want to literally concatenate coffeescript files or include one coffeescript file in another one? Are you trying to preprocess stuff for execution on client-side?

Comment: Why would you want to include one LESS file in another? I find it easier to follow dependency graph by looking through source files vs. slogging through Grunt config. As it stands I have to Grunt concatenate generated js files together to create what Foo.coffee with included Bar, Baz. etc. .coffee could do without an added concatenate step. Grunt works, I like it, fast, but difficult to parse the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to have a client-side module system, you should maybe take a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). It supports pre-compiling on the server as well. Another option would be [browserify](http://browserify.org/).